# Rspec: Save record after previous tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I want to run tests dynamically, using the loop. What I have:

```
let!(:product) { create(:product) }
let!(:data) { product.some_data_object }
let(:run_action) { patch :next_status, params: { id: data.id } }

STATUSES.each_with_index do |status, index|
  it "changes status from #{status} to #{STATUSES[index + 1]}" do
   run_action
   expect { data.reload }
     .to change { data.status }
       .from(status)
         .to(STATUSES[index + 1])
     end
  end
end
```

Each test should check if `data.status` is changed by one step from the array. But before each test `data.status` has the first value from the array.

So how can I get the old record with all changes after the previous test?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to persist data between tests is gonna lead to a lot of issues. You're better off running it all within one test:

```
it "should change status to the next one" do
  STATUSES.each_with_index do |status, index|
   patch :next_status, params: { id: data.id }
   expect { data.reload }
     .to change { data.status }
       .from(status)
         .to(STATUSES[index + 1])
  end
end
```

Comment: Okay, new issue - `run_action ` actually runs controller action only first time, second time it doesn't.

Comment: The result is memoized (cached) when you use the `let` helper. I've updated the example.

Comment: Yes-yes, I should use `patch` in the test, not in `let` helper. Thank you. But what do you think about the first question - how can tests be defined in a loop?